# Using Custom Attributes from Within Constructor - C#

Tags: c#, reflection

I am wanting to access the custom attributes on a Field in the class. I want to access the attributes placed on the field during the fields constructor. Is this possible?

Edit 06/28/09
Something like the below pseudo code

`class SpecialInt`

{

```
int _intVal; 
int _maxVal; 
public SpecialInt() 
{ 
    //Get attribute for the instantiated specialint 
    _maxVal = GetAttribute("MaxValue")
```

} 
}

class main()

{

```
[MaxValue(100)] 
SpecialInt sInt; 
public main() 
{ 
    sInt = new SpecialInt() 
}
```

}

Answer (score 6):

Sure this is possible.  Attributes are stored in Metadata and this is easily accessible during construction of an object.

```
public class Foo { 
  [Something]
  public int Field1;

  public Foo() {
    FieldInfo fi = typeof(Foo).GetField("Field1");
    SomethingAttribute si = (SomethingAttribute)fi.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(SomethingAttribute),false)[0];
    // grab any Custom attribute off of Fiield1 here
  }
}
```

Comment: What I sort of want to be able to do.

class SpecialInt
{
    int _intVal;
    int _maxVal;
    public SpecialInt()
    {
       //Get attribute for the instantiated specialint
       _maxVal = GetAttribute("MaxValue")
    } 
}

class main()
{
    [MaxValue(100)]
    SpecialInt sInt;

    public main()
    {
       sInt = new SpecialInt()
    }

}

And have the constructor for SpecialInt know the attributes applied to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can test them from anywhere. Attributes are inserted into the metadata for the type when you compile it. A type doesn't need to be instantiated to access field properties.